# Summing appearances of an object through a year

Tags: excel, date, plot

I found it hard to explain my question. Hope that it will be enough.

I have a table that looks like this

```
1999/01/30 V01
1999/12/31 V01
2000/02/31 V02
2000/02/20 V03
```

I would like to make a graph that would display a number of occasions of each V.

V01 appeared twice in 1999 while V02 and V03 each appeared once in 2000.

x - year

y - number of appearences of an object

I have created a table with all possible years a and objects as.
Now I think I need to have some kind of formulae to sum objects for me.

Comment: consider about using [COUNTIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx)

Comment: I came up with something like =COUNTIF(Sheet1!E2:E1604,"V01"). However, this counts all appearances. What about criteria for counting appearances in a distinct year?

Comment: try this one: `=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!E2:E1604="V01")*(YEAR(Sheet1!D2:D1604)=1999))`

Answer (score 0):

You can build a pivot chart with just a few clicks. Drag 
Date and Version into the Axis field panel and drag Version a second time into the Values panel. Group the data by year. This will produce this chart automatically:

[image]

To group the data in the pivot table by year, right-click any of the visible date fields in the pivot table and select "Group". In the following dialog unselect "Month" and select "Year".

[image]

Comment: is it available in Excel 2010?

Comment: Yes. The screenshot was taken from Excel 2010.

Comment: Ok, I found it. But how to group entries by a year?